# How to make a variable required if another variable is set to true in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to specify argument specs in a role, so that when the variable `manage_pubkey == true` then the variable `pubkey` is set to a non-empty string.
I have found the attribute `required_if` in the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#argument-spec) but don't quite understand how it fits into a simple `argument_spec.yml`. Is it meant to be used instead of `required`?

The example below seems to be wrong since it does not fail when `manage_pubkey == true` and no pubkey was given.

Ansible version: 9

```yaml
---
argument_specs:
  main:
    short_description: A role to manage stuff
    options:
      manage_key:
        type: "bool"
        required: true
        description: "bla bla"
      pubkey:
        type: "str"
        required_if: ('manage_key', true, ('add_pubkey'), False)
        description: SSH public key
```

Comment: You're saying that you're developing a role but referring to the documentation that relates to modules. `required_if` [is not listed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#id9) as a valid parameter for a role argument. And for the modules, the doc says _"Must be a sequence of sequences"_ whereas `('manage_key', true)` doesn't seem to match this requirement.

Comment: Are you saying it can't be done for roles, but only for modules?